# “one of the planets” vs. “one of the planet's”

Tags: grammar, apostrophe, possessive-s-vs-of, greengrocers-apostrophe

The sentence is

> The Red Sea, where the desert meets the ocean, is truly one of the planets most exotic and fascinating natural seascape environments.

and Microsoft Word cannot seem to agree with itself on whether it's **planets** or **planet's**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely ***planet's***, the singular possessive.

Comment: I thought so. It's just whenever I typed planet's, Word autocorrected me. I agree, it is more of a technology question than grammar. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @SandhyaKrish That’s just because Word’s auto-‘correct’ function has been told that anything that comes after “one of the” must be plural. Never rely on autocorrect. Computers do not and cannot grasp the complexity of human language.

Comment: Ha, yes, thank you. I figured out how to turn it off.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Appreciated.

Comment: @SandhyaKrish Really no big deal.